# Entity Framework connection string not from config

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, connection-string

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(string connString) : base(connString) 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitializer());
    }
//...
```

Need to pass a connection string to the context constructor. How should the string look like, for example, for SQL Compact? Tried this, but no success:

```
Context db = new Context("Provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;Data Source=D:\\Context.sdf");
```

**Edit:**

If I try this string: `"Data Source=D:\\Context.sdf"`

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled
>
> Message=An error occurred while getting provider information from the database.
>   This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. 
>   Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
>
> Source=EntityFramework

And if I try to mention the provider like this: `"Data Source=D:\\Context.sdf;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"`

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> Message=Keyword not supported: 'provider'.
>
> Source=System.Data

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx

Comment: @KrisIvanov, that doesnt work.

Comment: It would help to provide more detail than "no success".

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar error with MVC 4 code first (while running update-database). The error I was getting:

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the
>   database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect
>   connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure
>   that the connection string is correct.

Turns out that I was missing some crucial information in my web.config to get it all working with localDB. Here's the important sections (I used reference material from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ESTdb-01;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And for good measure, here's my whole web.config (I'm using MVC 4, EF 4.3.1, EF-Migrations):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ESTdb-01;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So exactly which part(s) are important? Why use a connection string *and* a default connection factory?

Comment: Thanks. It's not working for me still but the effort to make the solution simple was nice.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use always the EntityConnectionStringBuilder (System.Data.EntityClient):

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
ecsb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";
ecsb.Metadata = "..."; // your metadata
ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\\Context.sdf";
```

then you can generate the connection string in a simple way:

```
Context db = new Context(ecsb.ToString());
```

UPDATE:

Try to create the EntityConnection, then pass it to the context, instead of connection:

```
EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection(ecsb.ToString());
Context db = new Context(conn);
```

Anyway, where is the metadata? It's required by the EntityConnection!

Comment: It generates this string:   `provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string="Data Source=D:\Context.sdf"`   and i get `Argument Exception: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.`

Comment: Don't know how to do this with the **EntityConnectionStringBuilder** because all of my connection string settings are in the Web.config file.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (exactly the same error) it was solved by changing the default connection factory:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
```

Leave out any reference to provider in your connection string because it isn't necessary (this way). I think I read that by default the Database.DefaultConnectionFactory is set to SqlConnectionFactory() but I can't find a reference for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it has been solved by:

1- setting the default project in the manager console to the project that contains the desired web.config

2- setting the startup project for the solution to the same project in order for the update command to find the connection string.