# Connectionstring only works in global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string, entity-framework-migrations

I have a MVC 4 application using EF 5 Code first in VS2012.
I created this application on another laptop where i also activated migration but disabled it again (by deleting the migration folder and deleteing the table in de DB).
Now i copied the whole solution to my second laptop but i can't run the application anymore.

I always get an exception when trying to access the db.

> the provider did not return a providermanifesttoken string

with an inner exception

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"}

i use the following connectionstring

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When i put it in my global.asax it does work.

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
```

So in short on the laptop where i created the project everything works with the connectionstring in web.config but on my other pc it only works in de global.asax

Does anybody has a solution for this annoying problem?

Comment: Try changing connection string to your db context name.

Comment: I already changed "DefaultConnection" to the name of my context class but that didn't solve anything. And that still doesn't explain why it works on my other machine

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to the problem.
it seem like i missed something in my config.
I still don't get why it works on my other machine but for you guys with the same problem try the following.

I had the following in my config.

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
```

after i found this post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582193/entity-framework-connection-string-not-from-config) i replaced it with the this snippet

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```